# How may I choose which dotnet version, of multiple installed, a command is executed with?

Tags: .net, version

I need to run these 2 commands with dotnet:

```
dotnet new install Clean.Architecture.Solution.Template
dotnet new ca-sln
```

The first is for installing a template.

The second is for creating a project from that template.

I have multiple versions of dotnet installed, and it seems like dotnet 7 (the latest I have installed) is used by default.

How do I make sure the command executes with dotnet 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is managed by global.json

You can use `dotnet new global.json` to create a suitable file for the *current* framework, and then edit it to use any of the frameworks listed in `dotnet --info`. For example, on my machine `dotnet --info` says (among other things):

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.411 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.305 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.100-rc.1.23455.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

so I could use as my global.json:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.411"
  }
}
```

and now dotnet 6 will be used.

To see this:

(before, with no global.json)

```
> dotnet --version
8.0.100-rc.1.23455.8
```

(after, with a global.json specifying dotnet 6)

```
> dotnet --version
6.0.411
```

The system searches upwards for global.json, so it can be in the current folder *or anywhere higher*, and it will be applied.

Learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json - including things like roll-forward policies (so you don't need an *exact* framework match)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6 The `dotnet new` syntax is different. The `list`, `search`, `install`, and `uninstall` subcommands should be `--list`, `--search`, `--install`, and `--uninstall` options, respectively.

For example, the `dotnet new install` command in .NET 7 becomes `dotnet new --install` in .NET 6.

For more information you can visit [(Microsoft docs) Create a project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template)

don't forget to mark as answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much M.Nazari. What I am getting now is:

C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Tech\CA6>dotnet new --install Clean.Architecture.Solution.Template
Warning: use of 'dotnet new --install' is deprecated. Use 'dotnet new install' instead.
For more information, run:
   dotnet new install -h

Comment: I think this is because dotnet 7 is by default the dotnet version that tries to execute the command. I don´t know how to switch momentarily to dotnet 6 without necessarily uninstalling dotnet 7 (I would like to keep both running on my system and use them on a per need basis)

Comment: I am sure I have both versions installed because if I run: `dotnet --list-sdks` I am getting:
3.1.426, 5.0.301, 5.0.404, 6.0.201, 7.0.304 - and all point to this directory: [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: I ended up going to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk, and removing folder 7.0.304.zip. I created a backup of it on my Desktop, as I was not allowed to zip it in the original location. After that, dotnet 6 is my default version. I plan to extract the zip back into Program Files, when I need to switch again to dotnet 7. This is obviously not ideal, and I am sure there must be some flag that help do the switch more seamlessly.